# How prevent Blazor EventCallback reset selected item to default value

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I have a problem with the return event of a child component on **Blazor**.

I am currently using **MudBlazor**, I have created a component called `BrandSelect` which loads a list of brands that the user can select.

The `Brand` class I use in the select have of two variables: `Id` and `Name`.

This is the code of `BrandSelect` component:

```
@inject IBrandService brandService

<MudSelect Value="@SelectedBrand" ValueChanged="OnValueChanged" T="int">
    @foreach (var item in brands)
    {
        <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="@item.Id">@item.Name</MudSelectItem>
    }
</MudSelect>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public int SelectedBrand { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<int> SelectedBrandChanged { get; set; }

    private IEnumerable<Brand> brands;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        brands = await brandService.GetAll(); //Reading the brand from database
        if(brands.Any() && SelectedBrand == 0)
        {
            SelectedBrand = brands.First().Id;
        }
    }

    private async Task OnValueChanged(int value)
    {
        SelectedBrand = value;
        await SelectedBrandChanged.InvokeAsync(SelectedBrand);
    }
}
```

This is the code of the page where i use my `BrandSelect` component:

```
<BrandSelect @ref="brandSelect" SelectedBrand="0" SelectedBrandChanged="LoadBrandPlanning" />

@code {
    private async void LoadBrandPlanning()
    {
        if(brandSelect.SelectedBrand > 0)
        {
            //Do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

When the user selects a brand, the data returns correctly to the `LoadBrandPlanning` function but the item selected of `BrandSelect` will remain the old value.

How can I solve?

Comment: @user13256346 Amazing! It works, I didn't know about this "key".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in your `MudSelectItem` try to use `@key="item.Id"`:

***How does @key work***

Blazor in the first generates the expected DOM and compares then the current one with the new DOM and then applies the diff. The previous algorithm uses by default the element index for comparing but this doesn't work always correct specially when you have a collection of element like li because it will insert the last one without seeing the changes in the data, when you add the @key it will use a specific key to compare elements instead of using the index.

Comment: I believe this answer is wrong. It "solves" the issue as a side affect only.

Comment: @enet, I believe that you have a broad experience :). Could you please add your answer?

Comment: I did it.......